# How to avoid screen bouncing when adding a new MDI Child Window

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mdi

In my MDI Frame, I'm creating MDI Child Windows as follows:

```
Form frm = new frmMyChild();
frm.MdiParent = this;
frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
frm.Show();
frm.Focus();
```

So far, this works good, but the screen is shortly "bouncing", because the child windows are put to "normal" state, and then they are maximized again. How can this be prevented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if a MenuStrip is added to a MDI Parent Form, the [Form.MainMenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.mainmenustrip) is still `null`.
When this property is `null`, the System Menu controls of the MDI child are not *blended* with the MenuStrip (or the old `MainMenu`), so the child Form title bar is still visible and positioned above the MenuStrip.
When a new child Form is created and maximized, the MenuStrip *bounces* up and down while the child Form Caption is recreated.

Setting the `MainMenuStrip` property to the instance of the MDI Parent's MenuStrip, will cause the System Menu controls of the MDI child to *blend* with the MenuStrip (or the `MainMenu`).

It's interesting to see in the [.Net Source Code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Form.cs,6500) how many times this behavior and the design have changed over time (and it's just the comments there :).

**`TheMDIMenuStrip`** is the MDI Parent's MenuStrip created at Design Time and initialized in `InitializeComponent()`.

```
public partial class MDIParent : Form
{
    public MDIParent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainMenuStrip = TheMDIMenuStrip;
        TheMDIMenuStrip.SendToBack();
    }
    ...
}
```

Before:

[image: MDI MenuStrip Maximize before]

After:

[image: MDI MenuStrip Maximize after]