# Can I show the ToolStrip of a child Form in the MDIParent Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, mdi, toolstrip

I have an MDI Form and I want to merge/add the child Form's ToolStrip with parent Mdi Form.

Normally, a child Form's ToolStrip is shown only inside the owner child Form, but I want to merge it with the MdiParent's.

I can do it with the MenuStrip but hardly find the ToolStrip to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ToolStripManager.Merge()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.merge) method can be used to merge the MdiParent's ToolStrip and a child Form's Toolstrip. The child Form's ToolStrip will be *moved* to the MdiParent's ToolStrip.

The [ToolStripManager.RevertMerge()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.toolstripmanager.revertmerge) method will remove the child Form's ToolStrip when the child Form is closed.

Of course, use the real names you have assigned to MdiParent ToolStrip (here, `MdiToolStrip`) and the child Form ToolStrip (here, named `toolStrip1`) and  adapt the Forms names to what you're using.

Assign distinct names to the child Forms ToolStrip controls.

When you create a child Form instance, add this before showing it:

```
var child1 = new ChildForm1();
child1.MdiParent = this;
ToolStripManager.Merge(child1.toolStrip1, this.MdiToolStrip);
child1.toolStrip1.Visible = false;
child1.FormClosed += (s, ev) => { ToolStripManager.RevertMerge(this.MdiToolStrip, child1.toolStrip1); };
child1.Show();
```

If you have a MenuStrip in the MdiParent and in your child Forms, the ToolStripMenusItems will be merged automatically, but I suggest you add this right after `InitializeComponent()` in the MdiParent Constructor:

```
this.MainMenuStrip = MdiMenuStrip;
```

where **`MdiMenuStrip`** is the name assigned to the MdiParent's MenuStrip.

The reason is explained here:
[How to avoid screen bouncing when adding a new MDI Child Window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59674758/7444103)

Further readings (MSDN Docs):

[How to: Set Up Automatic Menu Merging for MDI Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-set-up-automatic-menu-merging-for-mdi-applications)
[Merging Menu Items in the Windows Forms MenuStrip Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/merging-menu-items-in-the-windows-forms-menustrip-control)

Comment: childForm.Activated += (s, ev) => {
                ToolStrip ts = (ToolStrip)childForm.Controls.Find("toolstrip1", true).FirstOrDefault();
                ToolStripManager.Merge( ts, toolStrip); };
            childForm.Deactivate += (s, ev) => {
                ToolStrip ts = (ToolStrip)childForm.Controls.Find("toolstrip1", true).FirstOrDefault();
                ToolStripManager.RevertMerge(this.toolStrip, ts); };   this worked thanks @Jimi